# Reading Twitch Whisper Messages with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, twitch

I have a greasemonkey script that adjusts some elements of Twitch.tv according to whisper messages from a chat bot on a specific twitch channel. My goal is to observe the whisper chat, read every new whipser message, do some adjustments accordingly and close the chat window afterwards, such that I do not see that I received a whisper.

I am not that familiar with Greasemonkey, HMTL or Javascript in general. The only way I know to do this is to use `observeDOM` on a class that contains all whisper windows (`conversation-manager`):

```
  // Observe twitch whisper chat
  var whisperArea = document.getElementsByClassName('conversations-manager')[0];
  observeDOM( whisperArea ,function(){ 
    NewWhisperMessage();
  });
```

As far as I can tell the observation does work reliably. Now to the part that doesn't: My method `NewWhisperMessage` itself.

First of all I want to describe my first approach. At the beginning I tried to find all new whispers. When a whisper is received the whisper window opens. The whisper window itself has mutliple message lines build up like this:

```
<div class="ember-view conversation-chat-line incoming" title="Sat Jul 09 2016 11:52:38 GMT+0200" id="ember2564">
<span style="" class="from">NameOfMessageWriter</span>
<span class="colon">:</span>
<span style="" class="message">
        Here is the message!
      </span>
</div>
```

Generally, at this moment I would just take the last element of class `conversation-chat-line` by

```
var allChatMessages = document.getElementsByClassName("conversation-chat-line");
var newestChatMessage = allChatMessages[allChatMessages.length - 1];
```

This works somtimes but is kind of unreliable since it seems that there sometimes are multpile messages arriving in one DOM-update (does this make sense?). As I noticed this, I came up with a more complicated idea which works more reliably but still seems to fail rather often.

My approach works roughly in 4 steps:

1) If this is the first new whisper of this session (`LastWhisperTitle` is still empty) then a starting point has to be found. For this I try to find the seperator element in the twitch chat window for the new whisper messages (of class `new-message-divider`. From there on I try to get the chat message right before that and store the `title` attribute and the message text of this message to uniquely identify the message (I can not use the `id` attribute since it changes when the whisper window is closed and reopened). This step is only done once.

2) Now I iterate backwards over all chat messages until I reach the last one identified by the two variables(title and message text). To get all chat messages I use `getElementsByClassName`. I store the index of this newest message and start with step 3).

3) Having the index of the first new chat message I start iterating forwards and parse each message in order.

4) Close the whisper window when a new message was read. (The conditional just allows opening the whisper window manually when no new message arrived)

And here is the final mehtod:

```
var LastWhisperTitle = "";
var LastWhisperMessage = "";
var ChannelName = "NameOfChatBot"

function NewWhisperMessage(){

    if(LastWhisperTitle == "") {
        // New Session: Find first new whisper

        // Find new message divider
        var newMessageDividerArray = document.getElementsByClassName("new-message-divider");
        var newMessageDivider = newMessageDividerArray[newMessageDividerArray.length - 1];

        // Find newest message already read
        var sibling = newMessageDivider.previousSibling;
        while(sibling) {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1) {
                if(sibling.className != "undefined"){
                    if(sibling.className.indexOf("conversation-chat-line") > -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
        }
        if(!sibling){
            return;
        }

        // Store this message as last read whisper
        LastWhisperTitle = sibling.title;
        LastWhisperMessage = sibling.getElementsByClassName("message")[0].textContent.trim();
    }

    // Get all messages
    var whisperMessageArray = document.getElementsByClassName("conversation-chat-line");
    var foundNewMessage = false;

    // Find index in array of the first new message
    var firstNewMessageIndex = 0;
    for(i = whisperMessageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        var currentWhisper = whisperMessageArray[i];
        var currentTitle = currentWhisper.title;
        var currentMessage = currentWhisper.getElementsByClassName("message")[0].textContent.trim()

        if(currentTitle == LastWhisperTitle && currentMessage == LastWhisperMessage){
            // This message was already read -> the message with the previous index is new
            if(i == whisperMessageArray.length - 1) {
                // No new message
                return;
            } else {
                firstNewMessageIndex = i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   

    if(firstNewMessageIndex == 0){
        // No new message
        return;
    }

    // Parse all messages from index to newest message
    for( i = firstNewMessageIndex; i < whisperMessageArray.length; i++){
        var currentWhisper = whisperMessageArray[i];
        var writer = currentWhisper.getElementsByClassName("from")[0].textContent;
        var message = currentWhisper.getElementsByClassName("message")[0].textContent.trim();

        if(writer == ChannelName){
            ParseWhisperMessage(message);
            foundNewMessage = true;
        }
        LastWhisperTitle = currentWhisper.title;
        LastWhisperMessage = message;
    }

    if(foundNewMessage){
        // Close Chat Window
        CloseWhisperWindow();
    }

}
```

I still have the problems that only some or none whisper messages at all are read. What could be the problem with my approach?

Comment: It's hard to say without live example. Can you tell us how to open that whisper chat on twitch?

Comment: We had a lot of issue implementing changes to whispers in BetterTTV because of the way Twitch implemented it in ember. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but if it requires modifying the whispers in the DOM you're not going to have a good time. We found that even small changes crashed the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem. My method itself basically works, the only problem is that when multiple whisper conversations are opened, all is becoming buggy since I use `document.getElementsByClassName("conversation-chat-line");` on the whole `document` which will also take messages from conversations from other users (not only the twitch bot). This messes up the values of `LastWhisperTitle` and `LastWhisperMessage`.

The solution is to put this code at the beginning of my function:

```
var conversationHeaderNames = document.getElementsByClassName('conversation-header-name');
var currentConversation;
// Find the correct conversation window
for(i = 0; i < conversationHeaderNames.length; i++){
    if(conversationHeaderNames[i].innerHTML.trim() == ChannelName){
        currentConversation = conversationHeaderNames[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        break;
    }
}
if(!currentConversation) return; // No conversation with chat bot
```

and then I just have to replace `document` with `currentConversation` and it works.